Remote debugging of a Go application via VSCode
I have a compute module 4 and I am running a go application, let's say cloud-bridge.
I want to be able to debug it via VSCode.
The application is part of an .ipk and runs as a service but we can of course get info about the application itself:
top | grep cloud-bridge
1455     1 root     S    1249m  33%   3% /usr/bin/cloud-bridge /etc/some-conf-file.conf

I managed to set up gdbserver on the Pi:
gdbserver localhost:44444 --attach 1455 
And the server started normally.
On my host machine, I located the executable and I run gdb-multiarch cloud-bridge, I set the architecture by (gdb) set architecture aarch64 and of finally I executed (gdb) target remote x.y.z.w:444444
The output was:
warning: Build ID mismatch between current exec-file /home/some-directory-different-than-the-one-in-the-remote/cloud-bridge
and automatically determined exec-file /usr/bin/cloud-bridge
exec-file-mismatch handling is currently "ask"
warning: loading /usr/bin/cloud-bridge /usr/bin/cloud-bridge: No such file or directory.
Reading /usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_arm64_dynlink/libstd.so from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading /lib/libsystemd.so.0 from remote target...
Reading /lib/libc.so.6 from remote target...
Reading /lib/libcap.so.2 from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/libzstd.so.1 from remote target...
Reading /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 from remote target...
Reading symbols from target:/usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_arm64_dynlink/libstd.so...
Reading symbols from target:/lib/libsystemd.so.0...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/af/fa1754a3493adf7887d1d3c7381728fec51c1e.debug from remote target...

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) y
Debuginfod has been enabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled on' to .gdbinit.
Downloading separate debug info for target:/lib/libsystemd.so.0
(No debugging symbols found in target:/lib/libsystemd.so.0)                                                     
Reading symbols from target:/lib/libc.so.6...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b5/f58205e91bc70fe14a7441aff3b8077011a6d0.debug from remote target...
Downloading separate debug info for target:/lib/libc.so.6
(No debugging symbols found in target:/lib/libc.so.6)                                                           
Reading symbols from target:/lib/libcap.so.2...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/87/aa78f98ba2b58ce0ead53814959ee1c7e9f7ad.debug from remote target...
Downloading separate debug info for target:/lib/libcap.so.2
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
(No debugging symbols found in target:/lib/libcap.so.2)                                                         
Reading symbols from target:/usr/lib/libzstd.so.1...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/a4/497ff175073b6b187761e734ad6be44003e085.debug from remote target...
Downloading separate debug info for target:/usr/lib/libzstd.so.1
(No debugging symbols found in target:/usr/lib/libzstd.so.1)                                                    
Reading symbols from target:/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/16/89bb134771f5cba5c773c46051b195d9ec15ad.debug from remote target...
Downloading separate debug info for target:/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
(No debugging symbols found in target:/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1)                                               
Reading /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 from remote target...
Reading /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/cb/5b80928d22e6142e1a45a5f91e4e6d339db3f4.debug from remote target...
Downloading separate debug info for system-supplied DSO at 0x7fb1039000
0x0000007faed7159c in runtime.futex.abi0 () from target:/usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_arm64_dynlink/libstd.so

To my understanding, I might have messed up the configuration for GDB and that raises a couple of questions.

Does anyone know how to fix the first and simplest GDB session? I am assuming I messed up with the parameters passing or the way I set up GDB.
The application is built in Go and it is already deployed, is there a way to attach this session to vscode and debug it? I am not familiar with the launch.json configurations egt choose either go or gdb etc.

